# Working with embedded images in a shared project

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to add embedded images to my shared project (no PCL). I added the images to the shared project (not platform specific) as *Embedded resource*. I'm able to use the embedded images if I use the following:

```
ImageSource.FromResource("TestProject.Droid.Images.Document Folder.png")
```

Simply using the string

> ProjectNamespace.Subfolder.Filename.ext

doesn't work as described by the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images). One has to add the platform namespace (iOS, Droid, ...).

Another option which did work is to edit **.projitems**. I added **LogicalName**:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Images\Document Folder.png">
        <LogicalName>Document Folder.png</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

but that isn't something which does work out of the box. There is no [Resource ID](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/57398/#Comment_57398). I also tried looking into the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages/EmbeddedImages.cs), but that doesn't start up at all.

How can I use embedded images in my shared project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images) only handles the PCL project. For shared project you either have to use the full string or add the `LogicalName`.

**Full string:**

Load the resource from the full string

```
ImageSource.FromResource("TestProject.Droid.Images.Document Folder.png")
```

The string is build like this

```
<ProjectNamespace>.<PlatformNameSpace>.{<Subfolder>}.<Filename>.<Fileextension>
```

`<Subfolder>` is only used if you have the image in it and for each subfolder you have to add the string. So you only need a mechanism to get the full namespace for each platform. Perhaps you define a property which returns a different string (managed by yourself) depending on the platform.

**LogicalName:**

Edit *.projitems* and add `LogicalName` for each image:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Images\Document Folder.png">
        <LogicalName>Document Folder.png</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then you can do this

```
ImageSource.FromResource("Document Folder.png")
```

It has been mentioned that you can add the *Resource ID* directly in Visual Studio so that you don't need to add `LogicalName` by yourself, but that seems not to be true.

So there is no easier way. The difference between PCL and shared project is also explained [here](https://nicolasclerc.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/xamarin-forms-et-les-ressources-graphiques-embarquees-tip-tricks-warning/) (in French).

Also the [Working with files in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) article explains some important details.